# Upgrade Pricing Tier of Azure Search Service without need to recreate service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there a way on the Azure portal to Upgrade Pricing Tier of Azure Search Service without the need to recreate the search service.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. Feel free to upvote in Azure Search uservoice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/12931110-allow-to-upgrade-the-pricing-tier

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Rudin - I did upvote already. :) That request has been around since March 14, 2016 with **no response** from the search team.

Comment: Thank you, @Zekokhan. Sorry for the delayed reply. Azure Search team take user voice seriously and review them as we plan our work. Not all asks can be included into roadmap. We will announce it once it's supported.